# The resourceprovider does not work when specified in the HttpService register servlet

Tags: osgi, vaadin

I am working on vaadin based osgi application. Before mentioning the problem briefly, i would tell what i am trying to do.
I have a main vaadin module which is a web app and has a corresponding vaadin ui. then I have sub modules which are vaadin custom components and they get added to the main module.

Ok, the problem I am facing is when I am trying to access resources from the submodule into my main module. The add, remove of the bundle happens but the getResource() is never triggered. I expect that HttpService registerServlet should try to retreive the resource when the URL is for example like

> http://localhost:8181/main/APP/connector/0/6/source/image2.png

```
public class Activator implements BundleActivator, BundleListener {

    @Override
    public void start(final BundleContext context) throws Exception {
        Activator.context = context;

        customModuleResourceProvider = new CustomModuleResourceProvider();

        context.addBundleListener(this);

        registerCustomModuleBundles(context);

        httpServiceTracker = new ServiceTracker(context, HttpService.class.getName(), new HttpServiceTrackerCustomizer());
        httpServiceTracker.open();
    }
    private void registerCustomModuleBundles(final BundleContext ctx) {
        for (final Bundle bundle : ctx.getBundles()) {
            if (bundle.getSymbolicName() != null && bundle.getSymbolicName().startsWith("com.org.app.submodule")) {
                resourceProvider.add(bundle);
            }
        }
    }
    public class HttpServiceTrackerCustomizer implements ServiceTrackerCustomizer {
        HttpService httpService;

        @Override
        public HttpService addingService(final ServiceReference reference) {
            httpService = (HttpService) context.getService(reference);
            try {
                final Dictionary<String, String> initParams = new Hashtable<String, String>();

                initParams.put("UI", "com.org.app.mainui");
                httpService.registerServlet("/main/*", new SimpleVaadinServletForUI(), initParams, customModuleResourceProvider);
            } catch (final ServletException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (final NamespaceException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return httpService;
        }
    }
    ...
    public class SimpleVaadinServletForUI extends VaadinServlet { }
}
```

Resource Provider

```
public class CustomModuleResourceProvider implements HttpContext {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomModuleResourceProvider.class);
    private final List<Bundle> resources = new ArrayList();

    @Override
    public boolean handleSecurity(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public URL getResource(final String uri) {
        URL resource = null;
        LOG.debug("URl CMRP {} ", uri);
        for (final Bundle bundle : resources) {
            resource = bundle.getResource(uri);
            if (resource != null) {
                break;
            }
        }
        return resource;
    }

    @Override
    public String getMimeType(final String name) {
        LOG.debug("Mime type {} ", name);
        return "image/png";
    }

    public void add(final Bundle bundle) {
        resources.add(bundle);
    }

    public void remove(final Bundle bundle) {
        resources.remove(bundle);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The path you pass to registerServlet should be "/main". You indicate "/main/*", but wild-carding is web.xml syntax. See section 102.4 of the compendium specification.